# Failed to run mongod, windows 10, "T�r: errno:11001 No such host is known."

Tags: mongodb, runtime-error, windows-10

I am very new, I have looked and looked but haven't found anything that helps. I hope this isn't a super obscure problem.

I am running windows 10 and have installed MongoDB. I am attempting to get mongod to run but right after it starts listening on port 27017 it kicks back:

> [HostnameCanonicalizationWorker] Failed to obtain address information for hostname T�r: errno:11001 No such host is known.

And that is where it stops. I have tried many things. I run the console in administrator, I reinstalled MongoDB, I have made sure the port is not being blocked by the firewall. I even gave trying other ports a go.
Everything that I have looked up says that where I am at mongod should now run and be listening on port 27017.

Here it is in full:

```
C:\>mongod
2016-01-17T02:29:30.059-0700 I CONTROL  [initandlisten] MongoDB starting : pid=1668 port=27017 dbpath=C:\data\db\ 64-bit host=T�r
2016-01-17T02:29:30.063-0700 I CONTROL  [initandlisten] targetMinOS: Windows Vista/Windows Server 2008
2016-01-17T02:29:30.065-0700 I CONTROL  [initandlisten] db version v3.2.1
2016-01-17T02:29:30.067-0700 I CONTROL  [initandlisten] git version: a14d55980c2cdc565d4704a7e3ad37e4e535c1b2
2016-01-17T02:29:30.070-0700 I CONTROL  [initandlisten] allocator: tcmalloc
2016-01-17T02:29:30.071-0700 I CONTROL  [initandlisten] modules: none
2016-01-17T02:29:30.073-0700 I CONTROL  [initandlisten] build environment:
2016-01-17T02:29:30.074-0700 I CONTROL  [initandlisten]     distarch: x86_64
2016-01-17T02:29:30.076-0700 I CONTROL  [initandlisten]     target_arch: x86_64
2016-01-17T02:29:30.078-0700 I CONTROL  [initandlisten] options: {}
2016-01-17T02:29:30.080-0700 I -        [initandlisten] Detected data files in C:\data\db\ created by the 'wiredTiger' storage engine, so setting the active storage engine to 'wiredTiger'.
2016-01-17T02:29:30.086-0700 I STORAGE  [initandlisten] wiredtiger_open config: create,cache_size=4G,session_max=20000,eviction=(threads_max=4),config_base=false,statistics=(fast),log=(enabled=true,archive=true,path=journal,compressor=snappy),file_manager=(close_idle_time=100000),checkpoint=(wait=60,log_size=2GB),statistics_log=(wait=0),
2016-01-17T02:29:31.063-0700 I NETWORK  [HostnameCanonicalizationWorker] Starting hostname canonicalization worker
2016-01-17T02:29:31.063-0700 I FTDC     [initandlisten] Initializing full-time diagnostic data capture with directory 'C:/data/db/diagnostic.data'
2016-01-17T02:29:31.084-0700 I NETWORK  [initandlisten] waiting for connections on port 27017
2016-01-17T02:29:31.897-0700 W NETWORK  [HostnameCanonicalizationWorker] Failed to obtain address information for hostname T�r: errno:11001 No such host is known.
2016-01-17T02:29:36.111-0700 I CONTROL  [thread1] Ctrl-C signal
2016-01-17T02:29:36.115-0700 I CONTROL  [consoleTerminate] got CTRL_C_EVENT, will terminate after current cmd ends
2016-01-17T02:29:36.121-0700 I FTDC     [consoleTerminate] Shutting down full-time diagnostic data capture
2016-01-17T02:29:36.137-0700 I CONTROL  [consoleTerminate] now exiting
2016-01-17T02:29:36.141-0700 I NETWORK  [consoleTerminate] shutdown: going to close listening sockets...
2016-01-17T02:29:36.148-0700 I NETWORK  [consoleTerminate] closing listening socket: 544
2016-01-17T02:29:36.152-0700 I NETWORK  [consoleTerminate] shutdown: going to flush diaglog...
2016-01-17T02:29:36.159-0700 I NETWORK  [consoleTerminate] shutdown: going to close sockets...
2016-01-17T02:29:36.168-0700 I STORAGE  [consoleTerminate] WiredTigerKVEngine shutting down
2016-01-17T02:29:36.864-0700 I STORAGE  [consoleTerminate] shutdown: removing fs lock...
2016-01-17T02:29:36.868-0700 I CONTROL  [consoleTerminate] dbexit:  rc: 12
```

Comment: Are you running mongod default installation without using any parameter or config file? I mean, just writing "mongod"

Comment: If your answer is yes to my question I would immediately try to bind it to a specific IP: mongod --bind_ip <ip address>

Comment: Yes just mongod. So I tryed mongod --bind_ip 192.168.1.1 and got: bind() failed errno:10049 The requested address is not valid in its context. for socket: 192.168.1.1:27017

Comment: What's the IP of the machine, do you have multiple IP's? Not sure if 192.168.1.1 is valid.

Comment: I am now wondering if "host=T�r" is the problem. I don't recognize T�r

Comment: There's a loopback problem there. Try 127.0.0.1 or 0.0.0.0

Comment: Wow, that's something that could be a nice bug to post, seem you're using a non-latin character right? I imagine you wanted to say "Tör" and for some reason Mongo cannot resolve it :)

Comment: First Yes mongod --bind_ip 192.168.0.39 (that is the correct ip) resolved  and came back to the errno:11001.  Second O_O That makes sense. Týr is what I named my computer. So if I change the name would that fix it? Ill try it.

Comment: I would try to use 127.0.0.1 first or 0.0.0.0. Another option is to bind a hostname to your IP in the hosts file, use something like "Tor" = 192.168.0.39 because it seems Mongod is trying a reverse lookup to get the name of the machine anyway. I would try to use an alias first to see if that works.

Comment: Nope! no need! Thank you! I changed the name of my computer to Tyr instead of Týr and mongod is working now.

Comment: Answered the question adding a bit more of information ;)

Answer (score 0):

As pointed out by Maximiliano Rios I used a non-latin character in my computers network name and mongod couldn’t handle it. So by changing the name from Týr to Tyr allowed mongod to run.

Under Control Panel\All Control Panel Items\System I changed the Computer Name.

Answer (score 0):

Absolutely weird but we found it out talking together. Seems that mongod tries to reverse lookup always the machine name and it has issues with non-standard characters (in this case is a non-latin character ö but I'm not sure what's the set mongo uses)
Changing the name of the machine works.

I would also try to set an alias in the hosts file.